# Problem with Vivaldi ppa

Tags: ppa, vivaldi

```
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:2 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                       
Hit:3 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease               
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:5 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease             
Hit:6 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x eoan InRelease                      
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Ign:8 https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb stable InRelease                    
Hit:9 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease                  
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease             
Hit:10 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ InRelease                          
Hit:12 https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org eoan InRelease                
Hit:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease               
Err:14 https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb stable Release                     
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 23.111.9.47 443]
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kritalime/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease            
Hit:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease              
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu eoan InRelease            
Hit:18 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                  
Hit:19 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease      
Reading package lists... Done
```

I got this error somebody who knows?

```
E: The repository 'https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb stable Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use `--allow-unauthenticated` with `apt`. Run the command:

```
sudo apt update --allow-unauthenticated
```

---

If you do not want to use `--allow-unauthenticated` flag every time you run `sudo apt update` here is a solution.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal.
2. Type the command `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` . In this file, search for vivaldi repository.
3. Now, replace the line with:

   ```
   deb [trusted=yes] https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/ stable main
   ```
4. Now, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>y</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the files.
5. Finally, update the package list:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

Comment: I didn't work i got this!  E: Failed to fetch https://repo.vivaldi.com/archive/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 23.111.9.47 443]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.